# How to set the text in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to set the answer using the `set()` method without writing it in the `text` attribute in the `Label` and also I want to change the message without displaying the messages over each other.

I want the new message to appear and the one before it to disappear. I tried to use the `set()` and `get()` methods but it used to return its default value without using the value in the `set()` method and I don't know why.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
root= Tk()
root.title("Project")
root.geometry('500x600')
root.title('Choose Answer')
var = IntVar()
textt = StringVar()
print(textt.set('Clicked..........'))

def Result():
    print(textt.set('You Clicked....................'))
    if(var.get() == 1):
        print(var.get())
        print(textt)
        textt.set('You Clicked')
        resultText = Label(root, text=textt , fg='white',bg='gray', width=40)
        resultText.place(x=100,y=200)
    else:
        textt.set('You did\'t Click')
        resultText = Label(root, text=textt, fg='white',bg='grey', width=40)
        resultText.place(x=100,y=200)


checkBox = Checkbutton(root, text='Did you Study Math', variable=var, bg='grey')
checkBox.place(x=50,y=50)
button = Button(root, text='Select', fg='white', bg='grey',font='sans-serif',command=Result)
button.place(x=50,y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Project")
root.geometry('500x600')
root.title('Choose Answer')
var = IntVar()
textt = StringVar()
resultText = Label(root, textvariable=textt , fg='white',bg='gray', width=40)
resultText.place(x=100,y=200)
def Result():
    print(var.get())
    if var.get() == 1:
        textt.set('You Clicked')
    else:
        textt.set('You didn\'t Click')

checkBox = Checkbutton(root, text='Did you Study Math', variable=var, bg='grey')
checkBox.place(x=50,y=50)
button = Button(root, text='Select', fg='white', bg='grey',font='sans-serif',command=Result)
button.place(x=50,y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

When you create `resultText`, instead of setting the `text` argument to `textt`, you need to set the `textvariable` argument to `text`. That way, the text of the variable is automatically changed when you change `textt`.

I removed all the lines where `resultText` was recreated and re-`place`d, and just created it once before defining `Result()`. Also, I removed `from tkinter import messagebox`, because you already import it when you call `from tkinter import *`. Just a note: wildcard imports are discouraged, so try to avoid using them in the future.